problem with geometry package
I have used the geometry package but the result was not good and it was as shown in the attached picture
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[showframe,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\geometry{top=15mm,headheight=10mm,headsep=5mm,bottom=15mm,footskip=10mm,left=1cm,right=1cm,textwidth=19cm,includehead,}

\begin{document}
    GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
        
    \fancyhead[L]{document}
    \fancyhead[C]{document}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{document}
    \fancyfoot[L]{2025/2024}
    \fancyfoot[C]{2025/2024}
    \fancyfoot[R]{2025/2024}  
    
\end{document}



This is unrelated to the geometry package. You are using the default US English hyphenation patterns and GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG is not an English word and no hyphenation point can be found so no linebreak is possible.

Instead of your GGGGG… use a dummy text package for testing.

@DavidCarlisle I guess the problem is not the unbreakable GGGGGG… but the to low head width and foot width.

Welcome to TeX.SX!

@cabohah yes I noted your answer. well spotted if that is the issue, I couldn't get past the GGGG and didn't notice anything else, but you may be right:-)

In fact, it would always be advisable for questioners to state the problem specifically in the text of the question. It would also be desirable to avoid irrelevant side issues such as the inseparable GGGGGGGGGGGGG.... While newcomers can slightly hope that we are also prepared to give speculative answers, the risk of the question being closed due to lack of clarity increases from such somehow unclear question to question.

It is recommended to load fancyhdr after geometry setup so that the initialization of \headwidth is correct. I would also recommend to do all setup in the document preamble instead of the document body (but the following example would also work, if you'd move the \fancyhead and \fancyfoot commands below \begin{document}):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\geometry{top=15mm,headheight=10mm,headsep=5mm,bottom=15mm,footskip=10mm,left=1cm,right=1cm,textwidth=19cm,includehead,}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{mwe}% for demonstration only

\fancyhead[L]{document}
\fancyhead[C]{document}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{document}
\fancyfoot[L]{2025/2024}
\fancyfoot[C]{2025/2024}
\fancyfoot[R]{2025/2024}  

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}


An alternative would be using scrlayer-scrpage instead of fancyhdr. In this case loading scrlayer-scrpage before setting up the geometry would indeed work:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[manualmark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[showframe,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\geometry{top=15mm,headheight=10mm,headsep=5mm,bottom=15mm,footskip=10mm,left=1cm,right=1cm,textwidth=19cm,includehead,}

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for demonstration only

\ihead{left/inner}
\chead{center}
\ohead{right/outer}
\ifoot{left/inner}
\cfoot{center}
\ofoot{right/outer}  
\begin{document}
        
\lipsum

\end{document}


Please note, that typographically your margin settings are not really pleasing.
